# How i can edit my htaccess file to let my site work with "www" only

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file code is

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to let my site work with  "www" only

i couldn't integrate this code with it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the full output of your `.htaccess` file?  You are showing a rule of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?_doroute=$1 [L,QSA]` which indicates stop processing at the end of that rule, [L].

If you are just adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

then that would be your issue.

An alternative method is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I have tried that..but it didn't work correctly too..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add the folowing to your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Source:
[LetUsLook.nl - Redirect  non-www to www](http://www.letuslook.nl/redirect-wordpress-mu-non-www-to-www)